# No video from Logitech Webcam C270 on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: video, webcam, logitech

I have a been using a Logitech C270 webcam for several years without any issues on my system with Ubuntu 20.10 currently installed. But starting yesterday the webcam stopped outputting video in Zoom and all other video capture programs. The light on the camera will turn on indicating it is capturing video. dmesg and lsusb indicate that the camera was detected but no errors are shown. I don't know of anything I could have done that could have caused this except installing kernel updates.

I attempted to go back to an older kernel release, linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic (the latest I have installed is linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic) without any change.

The only feedback I've been able to find is from running guvcview. Here is the output:

```
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.6
GUVCVIEW: couldn't open /home/etrochim/.config/guvcview2/video0 for read: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:642:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1090:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1090:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
GUVCVIEW: (status) saving video to /home/etrochim/my_video-1.mkv
ENCODER: add stream 0 to stream list
ENCODER: add stream 1 to stream list
ENCODER: (matroska) add seekhead entry 0 (max 10)
ENCODER: (matroska) add seekhead entry 1 (max 10)
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I'm curious whether you have this problem with your C270? Thanks. https://askubuntu.com/q/1369096/48214

Comment: @Ryan No, sorry, I don't have that issue. I use Zoom regularly and except for this one hiccup it has worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, once I posted the question I fixed the issue. The webcam is connected to my desktop via the usb ports on my monitor. I had originally tried disconnecting and reconnecting the usb cable from my monitor to desktop which didn't work. But disconnecting and reconnecting the webcam from my monitor did work. I have no idea why but at least I'm back in business.