# Webcams (both integrated and external) are laggy (and have no virtual background support) in Zoom 5.8.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: webcam, video-streaming, zoom-meeting, video-recording

I bought a Lenovo ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2 this summer and installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 (dual-boot alongside Win 10).

I've been experiencing many different problems in Ubuntu, this being one of them.

Google Meet video chats work fine.

However, when using Zoom 5.8.0, my webcam video is laggy*. And when I choose a Virtual Background, it never takes effect.

I've also tried plugging in a Logitech C270 webcam, but it has the same problem on Zoom.

I've reported my troubles to Zoom but haven't heard back.

*When I move my arm, for example, the image of myself on the screen moves after a slight delay, which is enough to be disconcerting.

UPDATE: This was happening on Zoom 5.8.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 and is still happening on Zoom 5.11.3 on 22.04.2.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report to me. Bug reports are off topic here.

Comment: zoom client on Ubuntu now has virtual backgrounds

Comment: @user68186 Zoom is a wildly popular product. I kind of doubt that there is a bug this important that has been happening for 17 months. It's likely related to my system, right?

Comment: The bug may be specific to your hardware and the Linux version of zoom. Unless the zoom developers have access to exactly the same hardware as you, they can't test it. If they get a bug report from you and the associated logs etc they can look at it. It is not a bug in Ubuntu, as the camera works with chrome, and presumably other apps.

Comment: @user68186 Ok, I've submitted another ticket https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/requests/16836541 and will update this question if I hear back. Update: They automatically rejected the ticket and encouraged me to submit at https://community.zoom.com/t5/Meetings/lagging-video-on-Ubuntu/m-p/108188#M61323