# Webcam Logitech C270i

Tags: webcam, logitech

The first time I connected my new Webcam C270i to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS it was detected and worked for a while with this configuration

```
$ lsusb | grep Logitech
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

The next time I restarted the computer it is detected with other configuration and it is not working anymore.

```
$ lsusb | grep Logitech
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 046d:080c Logitech, Inc.
dmesg
usb 3-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=080c, bcdDevice= 0.10
usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-1.3: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:080c)
```

My question is: Is there a way I can force the configuration back to the first one( the one that worked)

Comment: See [this thread in Ubuntu Forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958610) from 2012. their solution was to return the webcam and get a new one. Also see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347971/no-video-from-logitech-webcam-c270-on-ubuntu-20-10),